# Best way to handle such scenario where "smart cast is imposible"

Tags: kotlin

I wonder what is the best way to handle such scenario

```
class Person(var name:String? = null, var age:Int? = null){
    fun test(){
        if(name != null && age != null)
            doSth(name, age) //smart cast imposible
    }

    fun doSth (someValue:String, someValue2:Int){

    }
}
```

What is the simplest way to call doSth method and making sure that name and age are nt null?

I am looking for something simple as with one variable scenario where I would simply use let

```
name?.let{ doSth(it) }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that name and age are mutable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can nest `let` as much as you like so:

```
fun test(){
    name?.let { name ->
        age?.let { age ->
            doSth(name, age) //smart cast imposible    
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach, that might be easier to follow, is to use local variables:

```
fun test(){
    val name = name
    val age = age
    if(name != null && age != null){
        doSth(name, age)
    }
}
```

Last but not least, consider changing `Person` to be immutable like so:

```
data class Person(val name:String? = null, val age:Int? = null){
    fun test(){
        if(name != null && age != null){
            doSth(name, age)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answear. All the proposed solutions still feel like 'a lot of code to do simple job', at least comparing to let and single variable ;-/

Comment: @Panel I sort of like that it requires writing _a lot of code_ as you've put it. Although I must say I sort of like that fact since it encourages one to use immutable types and read only properties.

Comment: This is very good point thx. although I am not sure if it's possible to applay it every where ex. data comminig from server

Answer (score 3):

For the cast to be possible you have to make a local copy of the value somehow. In Kotlin this is best done explicitly:

```
val name = name
val age = age
if(name != null && age != null){
    doSth(name, age)
}
```

The `let` function hides this behind an abstraction layer, which is not the best IMHO.

Comment: not sure shadowing variables is a better approach than `let`

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice, little lib that allows for writing `let`-like code with multiple variables. It's open-source and you can find it on GitHub, it's called [Unwrap](https://github.com/importre/kotlin-unwrap)

Example based on readme:

```
unwrap(_a, _b, _c) { a, b, c ->
    println("$a, $b$c") // all variables are not-null
}
```

All `unwrap(...)` methods are marked `inline` so there should be no overhead with using them.

By the way, this lib also allows to handle situation when there are some null variables (the `nah()` method).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define an inline method that allows you to take N parameters in order to avoid nesting `let`s (I'm basing my answer on [this](https://github.com/ajurasz/ascii-less-gallery/blob/d882210cb69bae35f3b10e1c13e95fd4f73dea4f/src/main/kotlin/ajurasz/helpers.kt#L7-L9)).

```
inline fun <T1: Any, T2: Any, R: Any> safeLet(p1: T1?, p2: T2?, block: (T1, T2)->R?): R? {
    return if (p1 != null && p2 != null) block(p1, p2) else null
}
```

Then

```
fun test() {
    safeLet(name, age, {name, age -> 
        doSth(name, age) //smart cast
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take it a little "extreme" you could define an extension function on `Pair<String?,Int?>` that hides the logic for you:

```
fun Pair<String?,Int?>.test(block: (String, Int) -> Unit) {
    if(first != null && second != null) {
         block(first, second)
    }
}
```

then, calling it will be a little more concise

```
(name to age).test { n, a ->
   println("name: $n age: $a")
}
```

However, it won't really help you (since you could as well define this as a  function inside the `Person` class itself), unless you need this kind of functionality really often throughout the whole project. Like I said, it seems overkill.

**edit**
you could actually make it (a little) more useful, by going fully generic:

```
fun <T,R> Pair<T?,R?>.ifBothNotNull(block: (T, R) -> Unit) {
    if(first != null && second != null){
         block(first, second)
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates garbage. An inline function with 2 parameters would be more practical.

Comment: extreme indeed, but still its nice to know

Comment: @voddan please elaborate. plus the question was about creating a simple one-liner not to create the most efficient solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39246836/3255152) there are various ways to copy property values into function variables to enable smart cast. e.g.:

1. Intermediary function:

   ```
   class Person(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null) {
       fun test() = test(name, age)
       private fun test(name: String?, age: Int?) {
           if (name != null && age != null)
               doSth(name, age) //smart cast possible
       }

       fun doSth(someValue: String, someValue2: Int) {

       }
   }
   ```
2. Anonymous function:

   ```
   class Person(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null) {
       fun test() = (fun(name: String?, age: Int?) {
           if (name != null && age != null)
               doSth(name, age) //smart cast possible
       })(name, age)

       fun doSth(someValue: String, someValue2: Int) {

       }
   }
   ```
3. Default arguments:

   ```
   class Person(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null) {
       fun test(name: String? = this.name, age: Int? = this.age) {
           if (name != null && age != null)
               doSth(name, age) //smart cast possible
       }

       fun doSth(someValue: String, someValue2: Int) {

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problem while assigning text to textview with same problem description.
All I did was putting double exclamation mark after the name of my textview.
For example:

```
var name:TextView?=null
name = findViewById(R.id.id_name)
name!!.text = "Your text"
```